# PowerBuilder Serialize/De-serialize JSON from/to WordPress dbms

Tags: json, wordpress, powerbuilder

How to **serialize** or **de-serialize** [json](/questions/tagged/json) in PowerBuilder 11.5 (classic)?

WordPress stores JSON-like collections in the database and I am not aware of native functionality that handles this in PowerBuilder. I also cannot remember if it's possible to use the [.net](/questions/tagged/.net) Framework in PB 11.5 classic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this...

http://www.pblsoft.com/sailjson.htm

it is a native pb object which can be migrated to 11.5

Answer (score 1):

I'd write a COM visible component in .Net (C#) which handles JSON and use it within your PB application.  There are a variety of Open Source libraries you can use ([fastJSON](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/159450/fastJSON) is one).  There is a JSON service in the current version of the [PFC on Codeplex](http://pfc.codeplex.com/) but it did not properly parse JSON when I tried to use it a few years ago.

Appeon plans on adding native JSON parsing in future version of PowerBuilder.

Comment: Good solution +1 however native was what I was hoping for. Will check out the one on Codeplex.